# Warning messages for two groups of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Hi guys I have jQuery code to validate if checkboxes are checked, and if they are not warning messages are displayed. All works fine. There are two messages for two different groups of checkboxes. At the moment both messages are displayed under last checkbox. What I want is to display Agree message under "Agree" checkbox and Select one of the options under "OPTIONS" group of checkboxes. Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6pquz61/4/).

Here is a code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var checkboxes = $('.require-one');
    var checkbox_names = $.map(checkboxes, function(e, i) {
        return $(e).attr("name")
    }).join(" ");

    $("#itemForm").validate({
        groups: {
            checks: checkbox_names
        },
        rules: {
            resp01: 'required',
        },
        messages: {
            resp01: {
                required: 'You must agree before submitting!'
            },
        },

        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            $('#form_error').append(error);
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert('Form Submited');
            return false;
        }

    });
});

$.validator.addMethod('require-one', function(value) {
    if ($('#resp01').is(':checked')) {
        return $('.require-one:checked').size() > 0;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, 'Please select one of the options.');
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You saying that you want to display the two different messages in two different places, right? It's not quite clear.

Comment: I guess i misunderstood the problem

Comment: Yes, that is correct, 2 messages at 2 different places. One message under  "Agree" checkbox, the other under "OPTIONS" group of checkboxes. I might have asked question not clearly. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are. When you are in the `errorPlacement` function you could check if your `element` has a specific feature. Because you need to know which element has been validated before inserting the error message. In this case I used the class of the element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var checkboxes = $('.require-one');
  var checkbox_names = $.map(checkboxes, function(e, i) {
    return $(e).attr("name")
  }).join(" ");

  $("#itemForm").validate({
    groups: {
      checks: checkbox_names
    },
    rules: {
      resp01: 'required',
    },
    messages: {
      resp01: {
        required: 'You must agree before submitting!'
      },
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      if ($(element).hasClass("require-one")) {
        $('#require-one-error').append(error);
      } else {
        $('#resp-error').append(error);
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      alert('Form Submited');
      return false;
    }

  });
});

$.validator.addMethod('require-one', function(value) {
  if ($('#resp01').is(':checked')) {
    return $('.require-one:checked').size() > 0;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}, 'Please select one of the options.');
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 96%;
}

label.error {
  float: none;
  color: red;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form name="itemForm" id="itemForm" method="post">
  <fieldset style="width:200px">
    <legend>OPTIONS</legend>
    <input id="opt01" name="opt01" type="checkbox" value="true" class="require-one" />
    <label for="opt01">opt01</label>
    <input name="opt01" type="hidden" value="false" />
    <br />

    <input id="opt02" name="opt02" type="checkbox" value="true" class="require-one" />
    <label for="opt02">opt02</label>
    <input name="opt02" type="hidden" value="false" />
    <br />

    <input id="opt03" name="opt03" type="checkbox" value="true" class="require-one" />
    <label for="opt03">opt03</label>
    <input name="opt03" type="hidden" value="false" />
    <br />
  </fieldset>
  <div class="error require-one-error" id="require-one-error"></div>
  <p>
    <input name="resp01" type="checkbox" value="Agree" id="resp01" class="resp" />
    <label for="resp01">Agree</label>
  </p>
  <div class="error" id="resp-error"></div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for! You have saved me today!

Comment: I'am glad to help you out!